# Coil resistance and input current in stepper motor H-bridge

Tags: resistance, stepper-motor, h-bridge

[image]

```
Vcc:
type: charger
Current: 2.5 A
Voltage: 12 V

Stepper motor:
Model: JK42HS40-1704
Coil resistance: 1.65 Ω
Coil current: 1.7 A
```

When choosing resistor R1.1 and R1.2, should I reduce current to 1.7A?

```
12 V/(4.8+x) = 1.7 A 
x = 2.25 Ω
```

Or should I also take into account coil resistance?

```
12 V/(4.8+1.65+x) = 1.7 A 
x = 0.6 Ω
```

Comment: From \$3.2\:\text{mH}\$ and \$1.65\:\Omega\$ I find the time constant to be \$\frac{3.2\:\text{mH}}{1.65\:\Omega}\approx 1.94\:\text{ms}\$. That's one time constant. Five of those means everything is settled out by then. So approximately \$10\:\text{ms}\$ is the period for complete setting. What's your frequency of operation?